# Spring application for multiple customers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, alm

If I have an application that behaves differently according to the customer I am using it for, what is the best way to handle the code differences between the customers?

The 2 ways I can think of are:

1. for customer specific beans - annotate the bean according to the customer , and let auto-wire select the correct classes for me at runtime.
2. Have different branches in SVN for each customer, and thus different war for each customer

Comment: Could you try using `@Qualifier` ? It's like your 1st ways you said in the question.

Comment: keep common things in a maven `main project` and create `subproject ` with different logic for different customer. Add `dependency` of core module to the sub project. Keep different war and schema for different customers. In future, The requirement may change for only one customer in a weird way

Comment: For a hundred customers, would you create different SVN branches? or different annotations?

Comment: @VPK, If there is hundred customers then role based **behave** could be a solution (a trivial solution).

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Spring Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) for this.

You can define different beans and configuration for different profiles:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("customer1")
public class Customer1Configuration {

    // ...

}

@Configuration
@Profile("customer2")
public class Customer2Configuration {

    // ...

}
```

To make profile active you can specify it in application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=customer1
```

Or even better - specify as a command line argument:

```
--spring.profiles.active=customer1
```

Spring finds only beans without any profile or beans that match exactly specified profile - this means that when you run an application with "customer1" profile, Spring ignores "customer2" bean definitions.

Comment: What about `@Qualifier`?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: So all customers get the code also of other customers?

Comment: @GiladBaruchian exactly

Comment: but that means that a customer can potentially run the code with a profile of a different customer

Comment: but another customer has own properties. if you don't include this properties, it will fail, isn't it?